Geometry Nodes: track index changes on delete
I have a custom (named) attribute, which stores a handful indices of the mesh I want to eventually act on.  However, first, I delete some vertices, which changes the indices.
What I'm after is a way to "track" the index change on the vertices so I can reassign the values in my custom attribute.  The deleted vertices are not consecutive, so I don't see a way to do it.
Essentially, I'm trying to find a way through the geometry nodes to "map" any of the original vertex indices to their "new" values after the delete.

I'm not quite sure if I understand what you need that for or what you want to do with it...? Reassign the values in your custom attirbute? Assign to what? Attributes are stored on geometry, usually points or vertices, so if you delete vertices, to which ones you want to assign the attributes? To other not deleted vertices?

I'm just keeping it simple, if I go into what I want it for, it just makes the question more complicated and we get people saying "you shouldn't do it that way" instead of answering the question.  And yeah, reassigning the values would be one solution if I could do that.  The attribute is on vertices, it references other vertices, but if I delete vertices, then the indices change and that reference is no longer valid.
